# Vulkan VMA: Unwanted assertion triggered during exceptional exit

Tags: vulkan

I have a situation in my renderer where I load some DLLs and perform some validation within them. When the validation fails, I throw an exception from the DLL to exit the renderer with a MessageBox detailing the error, and also logging the error to a file. Because of funkyness with throwing exceptions across DLLs, in order for Windows not to terminate the EXE, I purposely leak some std::unique_ptr objects by doing obj.release(), when the renderer is exiting via an exception. The idea is that, since we're exiting via an exceptional circumstance, the leaking of these objects is acceptable because the OS will cleanup the memory at app exit.

I'm running into a problem with AMD's Vulkan Memory Allocator. The allocator does an assertion check to make sure all its memory has been freed. Since I'm purposely leaking the memory, in this case, I don't want that assertion to trigger.

Is there a way to manually release the VMA memory such that this assertion is not triggered? Since I leaked the objects that point that memory, I can't release the memory on a per object basis.

I wish VMA would have a way to disable those assertions at runtime.

NOTE: This is all happening during development, in Debug mode. For now, Release mode is not a concern.

Comment: Use a release build of the VMA?

Comment: I don't like to mix release and debug libraries. Have had issues with that in the past. Decent suggestion, though.

Comment: Since you are using Debug version, could you share the {version, file, line} of the triggered VMA assertion? You could also always build your own VMA without that assert.

Comment: Line 12346, Version 3.0.0-development</b> (2020-11-03), Almalgamation: vk_mem_alloc.h

Comment: It has crossed my mind to modify the file for those assertions. The issue is that I do want them in the normal course of events; I just don't want them during exceptional exit. An ability to tell VMA to just nuke all the memory, regardless of whomever owns the pointers, would have been ideal.

Comment: You could do `if (exceptional_exit) VMA_ASSERT(...);`. Thinking about it, you are also using the semantically wrong feature; this is not what exceptions are for (they by design unwind the stack). If you just want to kill the app in an unclean way, that's what `std::quick_exit` is for.